# K&R 3-2 overflow problem

Tags: c, overflow

I'm going through K&R and 3-2 looks like it would be easy to get into a buffer overflow

> Write a function escape(s,t) that converts characters like newline and tab into visible escape sequences like \n and \t as it copies the string t to s.  Use a switch

If I replace the byte '\n' with '\' and 'n', the size of s could potentially be quite a bit bigger than the source string.

I could just write this program and ignore the overflow but I would rather not.

I'm having issue wrapping my head around how to handle this?

I'm thinking having a fixed buffer size, perhaps something out of limit.h, and flushing the buffer to stdio when it gets full?

Comment: What are the types of s and t?

Comment: No pointers yet, so char s[], char t[]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the entire point of the exercise is to teach you that when you're dealing with something like this you either need to:

1. Shoot too high (make a buffer double the size of the original)
2. Take extra time (an extra pass) and pre-compute the required size of the buffer.

Comment: 1.5. Start with a heuristic, "likely" buffer size. Start working on it, and copy it to a new buffer only when you're about to overrun it.

Comment: @Ates: That's the worst of both worlds… amortized good performance is only useful when no particular application can hit the worst case every time. Furthermore that approach requires the most programming effort.

Answer (score 1):

s will never be longer than twice the length of t. Since this is an exercise apparently meant to help you learn to use `switch`, I think it'd be fine to assume that the caller passes a string in s that's of sufficient length. Or, if s is of type char** (or similar), then you're meant to allocate the string, in which case you can allocate a string of the proper size.

In a real-world function, you'd probably have another parameter that indicates the maximum length for the destination string.

Answer (score 1):

try adding a size parameter, so you know the size of the target buffer. If you pass a pointer to that parameter, you can return some kind of error value if the buffer is too small and pass the needed size back through the size param. Something like:

```
int escape(size_t *size, char *out, const char *in);
```